# How do I view the contents of a Micro PIC chip?

Tags: pic, microc

I am using mikroC PRO for PIC and am trying to take a snapshot of what is already flashed onto a PIC32 PIC32MX795F512L 100 Pin 512K PIC Chip.

Does anyone know how to go about viewing what's already been flashed? I want to compare what's on this chip to what's on another chip to see the differences.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a suitable programming device that supports your PIC such
as a PICKIT3. Then you can use microchip's integrated programming enviroment 
(IPE) which is included when you install MPLAB X IDE to read your PIC device 
and save the image to a hex file.

You can then compare hex files to see if there is a diffirence between them.

The configuration settings (fuses) for a PIC contain a flag that prevents 
reading a image back from a PIC when enabled, to prevent piracy. So it is
possible that you won't be able to read a PIC when this flag was enabled when it 
was programmed.

There is, however, no way to get the original C code back as the hex image in the
PIC only contains compiled machine code, there might be some dis-assemblers tough.